# Any way to cheat in iOS to get networking to work in background?

Tags: ios, networking, background

I'm trying to build a hack so that I can echo incoming TCP packets to local UDP (to connect to 3rd party control surfaces that don't support TCP).

I don't care if Apple won't approve it, I only need to do this on my own iPads. I tried pretending that my app supported audio but that didn't work.

Is this posible (without jail breaking?)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this but you might be able to do it by setting the app up as a VoIP app.

From the [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html):

> Rather than keep VoIP apps awake all the time, the system allows them to be suspended and provides facilities for monitoring their sockets for them. When incoming traffic is detected, the system wakes up the VoIP app and returns control of its sockets to it.

Comment: Can that "voip" app remain in the background while processing those packets?

Comment: I've tried several ways to get this working but everytime my app goes in the background, my app stops echoing so it's either not possible or I'm missing some detail.